# Magento 2 Migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am using [ubertheme](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration) tool for Magento2 Migration. But Step 5 : Migrate Products taking too long time. This step is running now for 5 Hours. I have 2105 products. Is it normal??

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked Network? It looks like the error was occurred during migration, for ex. MySQL server has gone away. Ubertheme's migration tool is user friendly, since all is done in browser, but it's only for CE (no EE) and you should also try standard migration tool - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate.html - it's run in console.

Comment: Thanks @KateSuykovskaya for your reply. I have a bad experience with standard migration tool. It is not migrating data properly. On the other hand I got a good result with ubertheme . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you have used our data migration tool. As your question refers to our old version on Github that we no longer maintain, I'like to add a note that we replace such version with a newer one - [UB Data Migration Lite](https://goo.gl/VFWxkM).

PS. Normally it takes our tool less than 1 hour to migrate 2105 products.
Kind regards,
An Nguyen
On behalf of Ubertheme team